# XML not parsing to NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, xmlreader

I am using [XMLReader](https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader/blob/master/XMLReader.h) for converting xmlString to NSDictionary and it is working fine to some of the xml string.But it is giving null dictionary for xml displayed below

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<THEME>
    <OBJ>
        <FORMBG>0x00E0E0E0</FORMBG>
        <ALERTBG>0x00B4B4B4</ALERTBG>
        <FORMFONT>0x0033001A</FORMFONT>
        <FORMFONT2>0x00575757</FORMFONT2>
        <FORMFONT3>0x003E3E37</FORMFONT3>
        <ROWSELECTORLIST>0x0000CC33</ROWSELECTORLIST>
        <ROWDIVIDER>0x00BBBBBB</ROWDIVIDER>
        <SUBHEADER>0x00A8A8A8</SUBHEADER>
        <SELECTORCOMPONENT>0x00C2C2C2</SELECTORCOMPONENT>
        <FOOTER>0x00796767</FOOTER>
    </OBJ>
</THEME>
```

my conversion code is as follows:

```
NSString *stringURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://202.58.232.138/mt/theme.aspx"];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];

NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *responseString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"response string is %@",responseString);

NSDictionary *dictionary=[XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:responseString error:nil];
```

The url is printing following data on browser

```
    0x00E0E0E00x00B4B4B40x0033001A0x005757570x003E3E370x0000CC330x00BBBBBB0x00A8A8A80x00C2C2C2
0x00796767
```

and printing on xcode log will display following data.

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<THEME>
    <OBJ>
        <FORMBG>0x00E0E0E0</FORMBG>
        <ALERTBG>0x00B4B4B4</ALERTBG>
        <FORMFONT>0x0033001A</FORMFONT>
        <FORMFONT2>0x00575757</FORMFONT2>
        <FORMFONT3>0x003E3E37</FORMFONT3>
        <ROWSELECTORLIST>0x0000CC33</ROWSELECTORLIST>
        <ROWDIVIDER>0x00BBBBBB</ROWDIVIDER>
        <SUBHEADER>0x00A8A8A8</SUBHEADER>
        <SELECTORCOMPONENT>0x00C2C2C2</SELECTORCOMPONENT>
        <FOOTER>0x00796767</FOOTER>
    </OBJ>
</THEME>
```

I think that's why it is not converting to NSDictionary.
please help If you have faced such a problem before.
When you pass above xml data to for [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:responseString error:nil];
at the place of response string then it will work perfectly.But if you execute above code it will display dictionary =(null).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you get in the error param if you replace NSDictionary *dics=[XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:urlData error:nil]; with NSError *error = nil; NSDictionary *dics=[XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:urlData error:&error]; NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]); Your error should be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Finally found the mistake:**

it is counting escape sequence in response string.That's why not parsing to NSDictionary.
I have added below line to replace escape sequence with blank.

```
NSString *responseString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
responseString=[responseString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
```

Now my code is running perfectly.
output is showing below after parsing.

```
xml dictianary is {
THEME =     {
    OBJ =         {
        ALERTBG =             {
            text = 0x00B4B4B4;
        };
        FOOTER =             {
            text = 0x00796767;
        };
        FORMBG =             {
            text = 0x00E0E0E0;
        };
        FORMFONT =             {
            text = 0x0033001A;
        };
        FORMFONT2 =             {
            text = 0x00575757;
        };
        FORMFONT3 =             {
            text = 0x003E3E37;
        };
        ROWDIVIDER =             {
            text = 0x00BBBBBB;
        };
        ROWSELECTORLIST =             {
            text = 0x0000CC33;
        };
        SELECTORCOMPONENT =             {
            text = 0x00C2C2C2;
        };
        SUBHEADER =             {
            text = 0x00A8A8A8;
        };
    };
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess dictionary is not initialized.

You should initialize NSDictionary *dics.

Comment: other xmlStrings are converting successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting the allocation

```
NSDictionary *dics=[XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:urlData error:nil];
```

in the callback of an asynchronous request ? It works perfectly for me.

I'm thinking maybe there can be a problem downloading the xml in the first place but you don't check for that.